# Convert position to Encoder Ticks for a differential drive robot

Tags: robotics, encoder

I am trying to calculate the required encoder ticks to achieve a given position.  I know that there are equations for if you have the encoder ticks, you can calculate the resulting position.  I am trying to do the opposite.  I have looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning#Differential_steer_drive_dead_reckoning but I haven't been able to solve for T1 and T2 without those variables dropping out.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve for T1 and T2.

Use `\delta x` = ... to solve for T1+ T2 and use \delta \theta = ... to solve for T1 - T2.
Then solve for T1 by adding the two equations (you get ... = 2 * T1) and finally solve for T2 by substituting T1 into one of your earlier equations.

The result is virtually the same for T1 and T2 except for a different sign in one term, as one would except.